# Can we Setup SAP B1 and SAP HANA locally?

Tags: python, node.js, hana, sapb1

I am developing a software which will be fetching data from SAP B1 for some statistical reason.

1) I have setup a SAP Hana Express Edition VM on my PC locally, its showing SAP XSEngine up and running, but if i try to connect with it using hdbclient its saying (Not a Hana Server), help me setting up some HANA Server.

2) Right now we are exporting DATA from SAP B1(Actual Enviornment) and using the csv to do statistics. but we want to access the the data from SAP in realtime from SAP B1 , is there any way to do that, for that we wwant a Trial SAP B1 locallly to Test , can anyone tell what are the possibles ways to that.

I have completed setting up SAP HANA express Edition on VM and on my machine SAP XS ENgine is running

*Error Message:*

hdbsql=> \c -n 172.21.100.71:8090

Username: hxeadm

Password:

- -10709: Connection failed (RTE:[200110] Invalid connect reply (server may not be SAP HANA) (172.21.100.71:8090))

Answer (score 0):

> Can we Setup SAP B1 and SAP Hana locally?

Of course we can. Here are the manuals for HANA trial and for B1:

[HANA](https://www.erpworkbench.com/sap-hana/install-hana-express.htm) / [SAP B1](https://www.blueoceansys.com.sg/blog/how-to-ensure-a-successful-sap-b1-9-2-hana-install-the-technical-bits/)

If you are experience some errors that means you didn't configured firewall properly. B1 installation requires SLD and license servers which I suppose you will not be able to configure yourself unless you are an experienced BASIS. Check this [official guide](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/38093/ARedesign%202018/PDFs/administrators-guide-9-2-sql.pdf).

Comment: Does it cost for a trial?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend installing HANA on your own PC,
you will need at least 64 GB RAM Power and also when, you will have very poor performance.